# Google SafeBrowsing API: always getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, safe-browsing

I use google safe browsing API. So I tested this simple code:

```
from safebrowsinglookup import SafebrowsinglookupClient

class TestMe:
    def testMe(self):
        self.key='my_Valid_Key_Here'        
        self.client=SafebrowsinglookupClient(self.key)
        self.response=self.client.lookup('http://www.google.com')
        print(self.response)

if __name__=="__main__":
    TM=TestMe()
    TM.testMe()
```

I always get this whatever the website I test:

> {'website_I_tried','error'}

Note that I had to change some lines in the source code after I installed this API because it was written in Python 2 and I am using Python 3.4.1. How can I resolve this problem?

---

Update:

To understand why the above problem occured to me, I run this code:

```
from safebrowsinglookup import SafebrowsinglookupClient  

class TestMe:
    def testMe(self):
        self.key = 'my_key_here'        
        self.client=SafebrowsinglookupClient(self.key,debug=1)
        urls = ['http://www.google.com/','http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js/']        
        self.results = self.client.lookup(*urls)
        print(self.results['http://www.google.com/'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TM=TestMe()
    TM.testMe()
```

Now, I got this message:

```
BODY:
2
http://www.google.com/
http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js/


URL: https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=python&apikey=ABQIAAAAAU6Oj8JFgQpt0AXtnVwBYxQYl9AeQCxMD6irIIDtWpux_GHGQQ&appver=0.1&pver=3.0
Unexpected server response

name 'urllib2' is not defined
error
error
```

Comment: The `KeyError` in the second case is occurring because `results` is a dict, not a list. Its keys are the websites you looked up, and you didn't look up any websites called 0 or 1.

In the first case, there's absolutely no way for us to tell what error occurred based on the info you've given us. Add `debug=1` to the SafebrosinglookupClient, and that should print out the actual errors encountered. Please post **complete** error messages, including tracebacks when possible, for all problems on SO. Otherwise there's no way for us to help you.

Comment: @user3479224 Yes, thank you, that is one first error, i will try to fix it now, but I think i will still have the problem in an other way

Comment: @user3479224 I update my second short code: I only get `error` as an output

Comment: That's because you didn't add `debug=1` to the SafebrosinglookupClient contructor like I said.

Comment: @user3479224 Sorry, I did what you said, you can see the full error on my question now. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The library](https://github.com/juliensobrier/google-safe-browsing-lookup-python) doesn't support Python3.x.

In this case, you can either [make it support Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) (there is also an [opened pull request](https://github.com/juliensobrier/google-safe-browsing-lookup-python/pull/4) for Python3 Compatibility), or make the request to "Google Safebrowsing API" manually.

Here's an example using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

key = 'your key here'
URL = "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=api&apikey={key}&appver=1.0&pver=3.0&url={url}"


def is_safe(key, url):
    response = requests.get(URL.format(key=key, url=url))
    return response.text != 'malware'


print(is_safe(key, 'http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js/'))  # prints False
print(is_safe(key, 'http://google.com'))  # prints True
```

---

Just the same, but without third-party packages (using [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html)):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


key = 'your key here'
URL = "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=python&apikey={key}&appver=1.0&pver=3.0&url={url}"


def is_safe(key, url):
    response = urlopen(URL.format(key=key, url=url)).read().decode("utf8")
    return response != 'malware'


print(is_safe(key, 'http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js/'))  # prints False
print(is_safe(key, 'http://google.com'))  # prints True
```

Comment: Thank you. I get a strange error however: ImportError: no module named requests`` even if i am using Python-3.4.1 (!)

Comment: @Begueradj `requests` is a third-party, you need to install it first. Ok, let me rewrite it using only stdlib packages.

Comment: Yes, Alexander, I bothered you with my comment while on the link of your answser it says I must install it. So i am installing it now and I will test again. Regards

Comment: @Begueradj glad to help, I've added only-standard library version.